# Difference between IF DEFINED vs IF "!_Variable!" NEQ ""

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there a difference between

```
IF DEFINED _variable DO something
```

and

```
IF "!_variable!" NEQ "" DO something
```

Comment: `IF DEFINED` run slightly faster. If a Batch file execute this test many times and took a long time to run, the difference in execution time between the two methods may be noticeable.

Comment: Please note that `DOS` is an Operating System from the 80s/90s! Please use the tag Windows instead.

Answer (score 3):

Not as such, no. But the `if defined` version works dynamically even with delayed expansion disabled.

Comment: Although not a common concern, but `if defined` has the *name* of the variable unquoted. If the name contains "problem" characters those must be escaped (for example `if defined a^&b`), and space or equal signs are off-limit (for example `if defined =C:`).

Answer (score 0):

`if defined` relies on command extensions being enabled. But `if defined` is common to use, as its easier to glance at and know what is being checked.

Comment: Honest question: Have you ever seen extensions *disabled*?